# Как перевести число из формата 8.33e-06, чтобы оно отображалось как 0.00000833?

Tags: python, типы-данных, числа

Как перевести число из формата такого, к примеру: `8.33e-06`, чтобы оно отображалось как `0.00000833`? По-умолчанию так и должно отображаться, но почему-то в итоге преобразуется в такую форму

Comment: [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ну, как вариант, укажите формат вывода через f-строку. `f"{8.33e-06:.8f}"` выведется в нужном вам виде.

Comment: по какому умолчанию оно должно так отображаться? По умолчанию как раз и есть 8.33e-06

Comment: Обычная "научная нотация", вы же видите, что число тоже самое, а знаков при этом нужно меньше печатать? Поэтому она и используется. Почитайте про форматирование, это даже в родных доках питона есть в ассортименте.

Answer (score 0):

```
print(f"8.33e-06 = {float(8.33e-06):.8f}")
```

.8f - означает сколько цифр после запятой(в данном случае 8)

можно в зависимости от степени

```
f = "8.33e-06"
print(f"{f} = {float(f):.{int(f[-2:]) + 2}f}")
```

Comment: недостаток этого варианта в том, что он жестко заточен именно на -6 и на знака после запятой в исходном числе. Если что-нибудь из этого изменится, что уже будет не так красиво, а то и вообще неправильно.

Comment: *на два знака..